# How can I open a bootstrap modal while another modal is active in vue.js component?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-modal, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have 3 vue components

My first component (`MultiplePhoto.vue`):

```
<template>
    <div>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-thumb">
            <tr>
                <template v-for="item in items">
                    <td data-target="#modal-option" data-toggle="modal"> 
                        ...
                    </td>
                </template>
                <option-modal id="modal-option" :product="product"></option-modal>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import OptionModal from './OptionModal.vue'
    export default {
        name: 'MultiplePhoto',
        props: ['product'],
        components: { OptionModal },
        data() {
            return {
                items: [1,2,3,4,5]
            }
        },
        ...
    }
</script>
```

If I click the `td` tag it successfully displays modal (OptionModal component)

My second component (`OptionModal.vue`):

```
<template>
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <a data-target="#modal-edit-photo" data-toggle="modal">Edit</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        ...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <edit-image-modal id="modal-edit-photo" :id-product="product.id"></edit-image-modal>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import EditImageModal from './EditImageModal.vue'
    export default{
        name: 'OptionModal',
        props: ['product'],
        components: { EditImageModal},
        ....
    }
</script>
```

In OptionModal component, if I click the `a` tag, it tagdoesn't display the modal (EditImageModal component)

My third component (`EditImageModal.vue`):

```
<template>
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                ....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'EditImageModal',
        ,,,
    }
</script>
```

There is no error.and I'm still confused how to solve the problem.

How can I solve the problem?

Please help me

Comment: What are the codes for showing modals? Please, provide the logic you use for handling click and showing the modals.

Comment: How can you open a 'mod E l' or a 'mod A l' ?

Comment: @ironcladgeek, I use bootstrap modal. There is no code to showing it. It's automatic. For example like this : https://jsfiddle.net/jasny/ZcLSE/. There is no code to showing it. It just calls by id

Comment: @V. Sambor, I call by id. For example like this : https://jsfiddle.net/jasny/ZcLSE/